# mobilize my django, python and google app engine website

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, jqtouch

i am currently developing a web application for a mobile phone. the website is written using google app engine (GAE) under python and django. i have tried using jqtouch to mobilize my website but jqtouch (or django-jqtouch) does not appear to be working.. any ideas on what i should do?

Comment: Is there an error? Please add some detail.

Comment: there is no error but the htmls are displayed as if there was no jqtouch added. i have tried installing the jqtouch in my project but the html view remains the same. same goes for django jqtouch.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Daniel
I'd try with full django + GAE for the django that's missing from pure GAE. There is a project called [www.allbuttonspressed.com](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com) that enables full django with google app engine. I hope it can do what you want.